# Computer based testing system development : PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I developed computer based system for a school using php. Because I don't know javascript that much, I used php and a little javascript to submit my form. From the teacher side, a question is sent to database. A student fetches the question, answers and sends to a different table. Each answer is saved to database before another one is fetched. The system including the timer were built using more of php than javascript, and it is working well on my local server. But a friend told me it will not work well on online server unless I used javascript through out. I don't want my client to see any error on my script. My question is must I use javascript for this project? Why won't it work on online server the way I did it?

Comment: Well we don't know the thing so it's hard to tell whether or not it'll work. How about you show us some of that code?

Comment: No you definetly dont need to. ( javascript on clientside is just cool for nice UI / animations etc. , theres no real need for it)

Comment: And be careful what javascript you are opening to users to see :) for sure db password on the javascript frontend wouldn't do mich good to your reputation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is wrong. PHP can work as well as javascript. All depends on the implementation. Don't bother - use the language you know the best.

If you run into performance issues, first review your program - logic of it. Try to do the profiling, and so on...

Programming language by itself is not responsible for very bad performance. It can affect the performance, but not very much.